# jquery draggable Cursor position and draggable position are not the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys when i try to drag my modal popup with keeping cursor on header. cursor is used to be on outside of modal and cursor is not sticky with header.

Here is my html:

```js
//Here is my draggable script:

    $("#reminderPopupdrag").draggable({
                handle: ".modal-header"
            });
```

```css
.followup-modal {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 380px;
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-header {
        background-color: #1c3f94;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-title {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 8px 5px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-content {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-top: none;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-body {
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-body #reminderdate {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 2px;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-body #reminderText {
        width: 294px !important;
        margin-left: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 4px;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-body #reminderclosereason {
        width: 90%;
        margin-left: 6px;
        padding: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-footer {
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-footer .defaultbutton {
        padding: 2px 10px;
    }
    .popup-dragable {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        left: 0;
        z-index: 999999 !important;
    }
    #reminder.popup-layout {
        left: 0;
    }
    #reminder.popup-layout .modal-body {
        height: 80px;
    }
    #reminder.popup-layout .followup-modal .modal-footer {
        height: 32px;
    }
    .reminder {
        margin-top: -1px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<div class="popup-dragable hideElement" style="display: block;">
        <div id="reminderPopup"><div id="reminder" class="popup-layout">
        <form id="reminderForm" method="post">
            <div class="modal followup-modal ui-draggable" id="reminderPopupdrag" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title">select_followup</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="errorInPopup" class="error displayInlineBlock"></div>
                            <table class="width100percent">
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label><input type="radio" name="reminder" id="reminder-1" value="1" class="element full-width verticalAlignMiddle reminder">close_with_reminder</label>                                </td>
                                    <td class="textAlignRight">
                                        <input type="text" id="reminderdate" name="reminderdate" class="marginRight5 displayNone">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <input type="text" name="reminderText" id="reminderText" value="" class="element displayNone width-full marginTop5" placeholder="add_remark_here">                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <label><input type="radio" name="reminder" id="reminder-2" value="2" class="element full-width verticalAlignMiddle reminder">close_without_reminder</label>                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <select name="reminderclosereason" id="reminderclosereason" class="element displayNone width100percent">
        <option value="">Select value</option>
        <option value="6">Advertisements</option>
        <option value="4">Another reason:</option>
        <option value="17">Checking  financial terms and conditions</option>
        <option value="16">Company not leasable</option>
        <option value="18">Future potential clients  </option>
        <option value="20">Offer is of vehicle type in which we do not do business</option>
        <option value="12">Open application</option>
        <option value="13">Order</option>
        <option value="10">Other ticket already in progress</option>
        <option value="11">Out of office reply </option>
        <option value="50">Portal, ad removed, payment, offer withdrawn</option>
        <option value="7">SPAM</option>
        <option value="9">Unsubscribe MFO Mailing</option>
        <option value="2">Vehicle/part is sold (indicate order number!)</option>
        <option value="8">Vehicle/part not on stock (is looking for something else)</option>
        <option value="1">Vehicles too expensive</option>
    </select>                                </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="submit" name="send" id="sendPreview" value="Save" class="defaultbutton displayNone">                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div></div>
    </div>
```

I have tried with lot of solution which i found.But none is worked in my case.
I have added code snippet.can you please check
Can you guys help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can  provide a  code example which can run~

Comment: @Anan i have added snipper can you please check once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the draggable props 'cursorAt' , like this (I have test,it's ok):

```js
//Here is my draggable script:

$("#reminderPopupdrag").draggable({
  handle: ".modal-header", cursorAt: { top: -80, left: 0 }
});
```

```css
.followup-modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 380px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.followup-modal .modal-header {
  background-color: #1c3f94;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.followup-modal .modal-title {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.followup-modal .modal-content {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.followup-modal .modal-body {
  padding: 15px;
}

.followup-modal .modal-body #reminderdate {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 2px;
}

.followup-modal .modal-body #reminderText {
  width: 294px !important;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 4px;
}

.followup-modal .modal-body #reminderclosereason {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 6px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.followup-modal .modal-footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.followup-modal .modal-footer .defaultbutton {
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.popup-dragable {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999999 !important;
}

#reminder.popup-layout {
  left: 0;
}

#reminder.popup-layout .modal-body {
  height: 80px;
}

#reminder.popup-layout .followup-modal .modal-footer {
  height: 32px;
}

.reminder {
  margin-top: -1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="//apps.bdimg.com/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//apps.bdimg.com/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/style.css">
<div class="popup-dragable hideElement" style="display: block;">
  <div id="reminderPopup">
    <div id="reminder" class="popup-layout">
      <form id="reminderForm" method="post">
        <div class="modal followup-modal ui-draggable" id="reminderPopupdrag" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">select_followup</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="errorInPopup" class="error displayInlineBlock"></div>
                <table class="width100percent">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="reminder" id="reminder-1" value="1" class="element full-width verticalAlignMiddle reminder">close_with_reminder</label> </td>
                      <td class="textAlignRight">
                        <input type="text" id="reminderdate" name="reminderdate" class="marginRight5 displayNone">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="text" name="reminderText" id="reminderText" value="" class="element displayNone width-full marginTop5" placeholder="add_remark_here"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="reminder" id="reminder-2" value="2" class="element full-width verticalAlignMiddle reminder">close_without_reminder</label> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2">
                        <select name="reminderclosereason" id="reminderclosereason" class="element displayNone width100percent">
                          <option value="">Select value</option>
                          <option value="6">Advertisements</option>
                          <option value="4">Another reason:</option>
                          <option value="17">Checking financial terms and conditions</option>
                          <option value="16">Company not leasable</option>
                          <option value="18">Future potential clients </option>
                          <option value="20">Offer is of vehicle type in which we do not do business</option>
                          <option value="12">Open application</option>
                          <option value="13">Order</option>
                          <option value="10">Other ticket already in progress</option>
                          <option value="11">Out of office reply </option>
                          <option value="50">Portal, ad removed, payment, offer withdrawn</option>
                          <option value="7">SPAM</option>
                          <option value="9">Unsubscribe MFO Mailing</option>
                          <option value="2">Vehicle/part is sold (indicate order number!)</option>
                          <option value="8">Vehicle/part not on stock (is looking for something else)</option>
                          <option value="1">Vehicles too expensive</option>
                        </select>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" name="send" id="sendPreview" value="Save" class="defaultbutton displayNone"> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```